# Send an array of binary data, and write it on server side efficiantly

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, binary

I'm using AJAX to send an array of images to a server, and write them on the server side.

I want this to be **as efficiant as possible**, and I'm pretty sure that what I'm doing now is **bad**:

1. Sending the image data as `string[]` is not efficiant.
2. Using `JSON.stringify` to stringify the image data is a bad idea.
3. Using `Convert.FromBase64String` on the server side is not efficiant.

---

Here is my **client side code**:

This captures the image from a canvas element and add it to an array:

```
ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
imagesArr.push(canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', JPEG_QUALITY).replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', ''))
```

This sends the images array to the server:

```
function sendImageBlock() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/AJAXServices.aspx/Upload",
        data: JSON.stringify({images: imagesArr }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {},
        error: function (xhr, status, message) {}
    });

}
```

Here is my **server side code**:

```
[WebMethod]
public static int Upload(string[] images)
{
     int index = 0;
     foreach (string image in images)
     {
         File.WriteAllBytes(string.Format("{0}.jpeg", index.ToString(), Convert.FromBase64String(image));
         index++;
     }
}
```

Any suggestions how can I keep this **clean and efficiant**? Get rid of using the `string` formatting and use Binary data **purley**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Uint32Array in conjunction with xhr2 (HTML5 XMLHttpRequest Level 2) to send your data in its original binary format.

> XMLHttpRequest Level 2 introduces a slew of new capabilities which put
>   an end to crazy hacks in our web apps; things like cross-origin
>   requests, uploading progress events, and support for
>   uploading/downloading binary data.

More Info: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/

```
(function ($) {
   // fetch the canvas data buffer into an Uint32Array
   var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height); 
   var data= new Uint32Array(imageData.data.buffer);
   $.ajax({
      url: 'server_address',
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: 'image/png', 
      // set processData to false to prevent string converstion
      processData: false, 
      data:data
   });
})(jQuery);
```

The data from the blob can be read in PHP this way:

```
<php>
    $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
</php>
```

Comment: Also - how do I use `Uint32Array(1)` in my case? For creating JPEG ?

Comment: you can convert the canvas data buffer to Uint32Array with :

var data = new Uint32Array(canvas.data.buffer);

Comment: Thanks, What about the server side code? What shouls the webmhod recieve as parameters ?

Comment: The data from the blob can be read this way:

$data = file_get_contents('php://input');

Comment: I'm using .NET, what should I state as the param type my webmethod receieves ?

Comment: sorry , i can't help you with .NET. But take a look to:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.inputstream.aspx

Comment: Using `contentType: false` - it does not even reach my webmethod

Comment: try with  `contentType :  'image/png'`  and let me know if it helped

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141266/discussion-between-koby-douek-and-colxi).